# HTML Parsing -- Retaining only the real text?

Tags: html, parsing, tags

As web pages have become increasingly more complex and allow embedding of all kinds of visual and audio cues, am I right in saying there is no way we can parse HTML web pages uniformly to get the real text? Consider taking a random sample of web documents from the web of say... 500 documents (just a number). As far as I can work out we cannot apply any single parser that will ensure that we only get the "real" text of the web page and not headings (home, products etc), various copy-right issue statements and other nonsense.

Of course we can (a) go through all documents manually and note the tags of interest between which the text we are interested in occurs or (b) sanitize the HTML using an automated procedure where we carefully pattern-match and remove tags + content that we are uninterested in. The problem with (a) is that it becomes infeasible for even small collections and for (b) we cannot possibly identify or predict the tags whose content we are interested in.

Consider this (a) a cry for agreement or (b) a way of asking if anyone knows how this might be solved and what software should be used.

Comment: There is no way of doing this automatically. There is **NO** standard tag or method of telling someone "real content starts here" in an HTML document. Either you manually parse the files to identify points of interest (and the hope that the site the file is coming is consistent about placement), or you resign yourself to having a db full of useless garbage, or a LOT of manual work.

Comment: Usually a site's "real content" is only shown when printing. Maybe trick the browser into print mode + OCR? Just a vague idea... If you're looking for something rock solid you aren't likely to find it.

Comment: What are you actually up to here anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a parser, have you considered using some content parsers' APIs? 
**Readability** is my personal favorite and they have a [great API](https://www.readability.com/developers/api) . Others like [ViewText](http://viewtext.org/help/api) also provide APIs.

Comment: That is a good idea. Thank you for the suggestion.